# Is there a way to setup TestNG depenency based on Pass/Fail

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, testng

Given the following testNG test setup:

```java
package testCases;

import org.testng.annotations.Test;

import framework.utilities.TestBase;

public class Scratch extends TestBase {

    @Test()
    public void test1() {
        // creating a web page
    }
    
    @Test(dependsOnMethods = {"test1"})
    public void test2() {
        // populating the web page with information
    }
    
    
    @Test(dependsOnMethods = {"test2"})
    public void test3() {
        // updating the web pages information with new information
    }
    
    
    @Test(dependsOnMethods = {"test3"})
    public void test4() {
        // deleting the web page
    }
}
```

The above setup is a simple CRUD test flow of automating functionality within our web page via selenium and testNG and each test has a specific purpose identified within the comments of each test method.

I would like to address the following situation, lets say `test1` passes however `test2` fails. I would like to re-attempt running `test2` however if `test1` already passed then just run `test2`. If `test1` failed then rerun `test1` before `test2`.

My thoughts are if test2 fails and we do have web page that was successfully created, instead of wasting time rerunning test1 again, lets just rerun test2. However with its current implementation testNG will rerun test1 regardless on a retry.

Two solutions i have thought about is to do one the following:

- Clean up all data that was generated from any of the tests before re-attempting. Thus making sense that it will rerun test1
- Make the data generated unique every time its created, thus not running into problems when test1 reruns.

However it will take some time to add the logic to understand both of the solutions, was wondering if i had cheat way of not having to do this?

Comment: _....However with its current implementation testNG will rerun test1 regardless on a retry...._ How have you currently implemented the retry mechanism?

Comment: @GauthamM sorry should have been a bit more clear on that. Im using the run failed test functinality offered in the testNG plugin for Eclipse. Basically it executes the testngfailed.xml found in the test-output. However i wonder what a retry analyzer would do.....?

Comment: retry analyzer would automatically be called when test fails. i can add that as an answer

Comment: but when the retry analyzer is called will testng still execute test1 regardless of test pass/fail due to the dependsOnMethods?

Comment: test1 would be executed only one if it passes. I have added an answer using retry analyzer. Please check

Answer (score 0):

You could create a `RetryAnalyzer` class as below:

```java
public class RetryAnalyzer implements IRetryAnalyzer {
    private String name = ""; // last failed executed test.
    private int count = 0; // number of failures
    private static final int MAX_LIMIT = 5;

    @Override
    public boolean retry(ITestResult result) {
        String testName = result.getName();
        if(!testName.equals(name)) {
            // new test
            count = 0;
            name = testName;    
        }
        if(count < MAX_LIMIT) {
            count++;
            return true;
        }
        // max limit reached
        return false;
    }
}
```

Currently testNG doesn't support specifying retryAnalyzer at the class level.(may be available in latest/future versions). So currently I am adding the `retryAnalyzer` property to every class.

```java
public class MyTest {
    @Test(retryAnalyzer = RetryAnalyzer.class)
    public void test1() {
        // creating a web page
    }
    
    @Test(dependsOnMethods = {"test1"}, retryAnalyzer = RetryAnalyzer.class)
    public void test2() {
        // populating the web page with information
    }
        
    @Test(dependsOnMethods = {"test2"}, retryAnalyzer = RetryAnalyzer.class)
    public void test3() {
        // updating the web pages information with new information
    }   
    
    @Test(dependsOnMethods = {"test3"}, retryAnalyzer = RetryAnalyzer.class)
    public void test4() {
        // deleting the web page
    }
}
```

Here `test1` would **NOT** be rerun if it passes and `test2` fails. Only `test2` would be retried. If `test2` passes before specified maximum limit is reached `test3` would be executed as so on.

A passed test would be run **only once**. If any test does not pass before reaching the limit, then the dependent tests would be marked as skipped.